# when I use the return keyword in my code, I get only the first value of a list return instead of all

Tags: javascript, json

I wrote a function which when I use the return keyword, I only get the first item of the list returned instead of all items. The code works properly without the return keyword.

code snippet

```
function generateNames(){
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const playersName = fetch('https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?per_page=5')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json['data'][i]['first_name']))
    // return playersName
  }
} 
generateNames()
```

The result i get is;

```
Ike
Ron
Jabari
MarShon
Lorenzo
```

but when I uncomment the, `return playersName` line of code, I only get the first value returned.

The result i get is;

```
Ike
```

After refactoring the code:

```js
async function generateNames() {
  var playerList = [];
  const playersName = await fetch('https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?per_page=5')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        playerList.push(json['data'][i]['first_name'])
    })
  // return playersName
  return playerList;
}
(async () => console.log(await generateNames()))()
```

Comment: When you return, the function stops, so the loop stops.

Comment: The return statement shouldn't be in the loop.

Comment: You need to collect all the names in an array, and return that.

Comment: You shouldn't make the fetch request inside the loop, either. You should fetch once and the loop through the items, which would occur inside the second `.then` handler.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the useful insight. I just observed my mistakes now, I moved the return playersName below the closing brackets and now it returns all items and then I get an error saying, "ReferenceError: playersName is not defined"

Comment: @Barmar, I refactored the code, could you have a look at it and suggest if I am still missing out on something.

Comment: @Tom, I refactored the code, could you have a look at it and suggest if I am still missing out on something.

Comment: Looks good to me. You should post that in an answer, not the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```js
async function fetchPlayerNames( count = 1 ) {
    let playersResponse = await fetch(`https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?per_page=${count}`)
    let players = await playersResponse.json()
    let desiredPlayers = players.data.slice(0, count)
    return desiredPlayers.map( player => player.first_name )
}

(async function main() {
    let names = await fetchPlayerNames(5)
    console.log(names)
})()
```

Some notes:

1. async/await is easier to work with than chaining `.then` handlers, so if your function can be marked async (and some cannot), you should have a strong preference to avoid any `.then` or `.catch` inside that function. Your refactor makes the function async, but continues to use `.then`.
2. Your refactor won't work anyway, because `return playerList` will execute *before* either of the `.then` functions executes. As a result, I'd expect your refactor to return an empty array immediately every time.
3. Even though your refactor immediately returns an empty dataset, it still makes the API call *five times*. That is silly. The URL suggests that the API response can include multiple players, and so your plan should be: (1) make a single request that contains all the rows you want, and then (2) extract the items from that list that you want. If you are careless about making extra network calls, the people who own the API may ultimately block your application because it wastes resources.
4. Avoid hard-coding things like the `5`. That is what is known as a "[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))". Instead, your function should be provided with the desired number. Calling code will get the correct number from a settings file or user input or something else. My version takes it as an argument, but hard-codes it at the call site because there's not really a better place in such a small code sample.
5. I am going to criticize your naming. **Naming matters.** Your function does not "generate" names -- it does not create or invent names randomly, but that is what the English word "generate" implies. Your function *downloads* names from the internet (the correct verb for which is "fetch"). If you name your functions badly, your app will become a mess.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, I guess I have gotten a good grasp of my mistakes now and definitely improve on them.